# Azure Purview - Pricing Billing API Rate Limits FAQ Resources?

Tags: azure, azure-purview

Where can I look for Azure Purview - Pricing Billing API Rate Limits?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it relates to the business practices of a particular service, and not a specific programming question.

Answer (score 0):

**Azure Purview Pricing, Billing, API Rate Limits FAQ Resources**

| Item | Purview Resources Link |
| --- | --- |
| Pricing Guide | Link https://azure.microsoft.com/pricing/details/azure-purview/#pricing |
| Pricing Calculator | Link https://azure.microsoft.com/pricing/calculator/ |
| Quotas & Rate Limits | Link https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/purview/how-to-manage-quotas |

- Capacity Units - 1 CU Limit = 2GB Metadata Size + 25 IOPS
- Before GA : Customers can provision either 4 CU or 16 CU per account
- Post GA (October 2021 and Beyond) - Catalog Size starts with 1 CU by default and then scales up to 64 CU Max depending on size of scanned data estate metadata.